# Prove the following logical implications

Tags: logic

Prove the following logical implications:

(a) $\forall v_1 Qv_1\models Qv_1$

(b)$Qv_1\models \forall v_1  Qv_1$

The two questions are extracted from the book 'A Mathematical Introduction to Logic' by Enderton, Chapter 2, section Truth and Models.

According to the book, (a) is correct while (b) is not correct. But I have no idea on how to prove it. I stare at the definition of logical implication for an hour, still have no idea how to start. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to use the definition of [logical implication](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA88), page 88 :

> **DEFINITION**. Let $\Gamma$ be a set of wffs, $\varphi$ a wff. Then $\Gamma$ *logically implies* $\varphi$, written $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$, iff for every structure $\mathfrak A$ for the language and every function $s : V \to |\mathfrak A|$ such that $\mathfrak A$ satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ with $s$, $\mathfrak A$ also satisfies $\varphi$ with $s$.

and the clause of the definition of *satisfaction* for an universally quantified formula, page 84 :

> 4. $\mathfrak A \vDash ∀x \varphi[s]$ iff for every $d \in |\mathfrak A|$, we have $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi[s(x|d)]$.

Thus, for :

> (a) $∀v_1 Qv_1 \vDash Qv_1$

we have to show that for every structure $\mathfrak A$ for the language and every function $s$ such that $\mathfrak A$ satisfies $∀v_1 Qv_1$ with $s$, $\mathfrak A$ also satisfies $Qv_1$ with $s$.

But $\mathfrak A$ satisfies $∀v_1 Qv_1$ with $s$ iff for every $d \in |\mathfrak A|$, we have $\mathfrak A \vDash Qv_1[s(v_1|d)]$.

But if $\mathfrak A \vDash Qv_1[s(v_1|d)]$ for any $d$ also the "original" $s$ will do, i.e. $\mathfrak A \vDash Qv_1[s]$, i.e. $\mathfrak A$ satisfies $Qv_1$ with $s$.

---

The same approach will give us a counter-example to :

> (b) $Qv_1 \vDash ∀v_1Qv_1$.

It is enough to consider an interpretation for $Q$ such that it holds for some elements of the domain but not all:

Consider the domain $\mathbb N$ of the *natural* numbers and interpret $Q$ as : $n > 0$.

Thus the "translation" of (b) is :

> $(v_1 > 0) \vDash \forall v_1(v_1 > 0)$

and we cam immediately see that it does not hold.

For a proof, consider : $s : V \to \mathbb N$ such that $s(v_1)=1$; thus :

> $\mathbb N \vDash (v_1 > 0)[s]$

because : $1 > 0$.

But $\mathbb N \nvDash (v_1 > 0)[s(v_1|0)]$, because it is not true that : $0 > 0$, and thus it is not true that for every $d \in \mathbb N$, we have $\mathbb N \vDash (v_1 > 0)[s(v_1|d)]$.

Comment: How would one apply s(x|d) if there was more than 1 quantifier?

Comment: @Rickkwa - you have to apply the def step-by-step : $A \vDash \forall x \exists y \varphi$  **iff** for every $d \in A : A \vDash \exists y \varphi [s(x|d)]$; in turn, this holds iff $\varphi[s(x|d)(y|e)]$ holds for some $e \in A$.